# React JS - Google Map Marking Not Working in alt framework

Tags: reactjs, alt

I have tried to do google map with marking using 'google-map-react' but marking places in map is not working.I need to mark places dynamically on page load .

I have referenced this URL https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react

Please Provide a solution as a sample code or provide any reference url.I am hoping to hear from more experienced React developers.

Thanks

Comment: Please see samples here http://istarkov.github.io/google-map-react/map/main

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.